# Efficient Query for Bulk Delete in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, sql-delete

I have to delete records from a table 'project' where internally it has to delete (2000-3000) records from a table 'test_suite' because project_id is foreign key in the test_suite table. The database is Postgres.

I am using the following JPA query to delete the records from table 'test_suite':

```
testSuiteRepository.deleteInBatchByProjectIdAndAutoGenerated(projectId, true);
```

This delete is consuming time and delete from the project table ends up throwing an exception that FK constraint violated.

Is there any efficient query for BULK DELETE in POSTGRES?

Comment: please share the table structure with sample data.

Comment: Deleting only a few thousands rows should not take very long. Are all foreign keys _referencing_ that table properly indexed? You should get the execution plan using `explain (analyze, buffers)` to check where the time is spent